# Error deploying Primefaces 8.0 project on Jboss EAP 7.2

Tags: primefaces, jboss

This is the error running Primefaces 8.0 please note that it ran with Primefaces 6.1 fine.

07:24:10,717 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 224) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001 for context '/ais'

07:24:36,289 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 224) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: java.lang.String findComponentClientId(java.lang.String)

```
   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processFunctions(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:680)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:331)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:271)

   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:445)

   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:237)

   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)

   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)

   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)

   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)

   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$843/1466016034.call(Unknown Source)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$844/113487826.call(Unknown Source)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$844/113487826.call(Unknown Source)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$844/113487826.call(Unknown Source)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$844/113487826.call(Unknown Source)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$844/113487826.call(Unknown Source)

   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)

   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)

   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)

   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)

   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
```

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: java.lang.String findComponentClientId(java.lang.String)

```
   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.createMethod(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:721)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processFunctions(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:677)

   ... 32 more
```

07:24:36,294 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 224) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."ais-ear-1.0.0.ear"."ais-web-1.0.0.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."ais-ear-1.0.0.ear"."ais-web-1.0.0.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: java.lang.String findComponentClientId(java.lang.String)

```
   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)

   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)

   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)

   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)

   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: java.lang.String findComponentClientId(java.lang.String)

```
   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)

   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)

   ... 8 more
```

Comment: The method findComponentClientId is deprecated and removed in Primefaces 8.0. My application is running on Jboss EAP 7.2 which support JSF 2.3 api. I don't understand why it called a deprecated method in Primefaces 8.0 (built on JSF 2.3 API)

Comment: Have you check if you have multiple PF jar (and or PF extension jar) within your ear?

Comment: thank you for your help. My mistake putting 2 version of Primefaces accidentally causing this issue. (6.1 and 8.0)